# Automatically Loading At App Start

Tags: objective-c, timer, startup

[Cocoa/Objective-C]
I adapted a timer routine (for current time) from this site (and it works great - thanks).  It's currently attached to a button.
My question is: How do I make it start when my app starts up (and not use a button)  (in other languages, I'd simply put the action listener or timer in the Form)...?

Thank for any help on this!

Answer (score 7):

In your application delegate you'll find a method called

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

I guess that would be where to start a timer on app startup.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in your `awakeFromNib` method. This is called on all objects that get deserialized from your nib (like your application delegate), but it isn't called until all objects are deserialized and wired (so you can use your text field, for instance). For example:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)timer
{
  NSLog(@"Timer completed!");
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Obviously, in this simple example the timer could have been created in either the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method or the `awakeFromNib` method since it doesn't interact with any other serialized objects, but in your case, it sounds like you need the `awakeFromNib` method.